# Unrecognized tag prefix or device filter 'asp' - MVC ViewPage With Master Page Specified In Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC view page that uses a master page. The master page is not specified at the top of the view, but is specified in the Controller using the following method on the Controller class:

```
ViewResult View(string viewName, string masterName, object model)
```

This runs fine, but Visual Studio 2008 gives a warning in the aspx page: "Unrecognized tag prefix or device filter 'asp'".

If I add the MasterPageFile property to the view then the warning goes away. I can't leave the master page specified here as it can be changed dynamically.

Not a big issue, just slightly annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it is complaining about the `<asp:Content>` element in your view.  Without a statically defined master page, this element is orphaned as far as Visual Studio is able to tell.

I don't think there is any harm to defining the master page within your view and then redefining it programmatically as you have in your action method.

Comment: Yeah, cool. I don't really like having the master page specified in the view because I think it is a bit misleading, but I guess I'm being rather fastidious.

Comment: Whichever is less painful for you: the misleading nature of a master page never used or the irritation of a pointless warning message.

Answer (score 0):

I dynamically swap masters all the time--you can leave that property in there, and it will get replaced as appropriate. Just pick a default master file and run with it man.

Now, if you are still getting the error, make sure you don't forget the `runat="server"` in your `asp:Content` tag. Yeah, I lost an hour of my life on that one . . .